# Ler dados a partir de uma url

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, request

Gostaria de obter dados a partir de um endereço de url

Pesquisando encontrei [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11116250/6754506) resposta

Implementei para minha realidade

```
var http = require('http');

            var options = {
                host: 'http://192.168.1.6',
                path: '/sistema.cgi?lermc=0,33:80'
            }
            var request = http.request(options, function (res) {
                var data = '';
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(data);

                });
            });
            request.on('error', function (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            });
            request.end();
```

Adaptei para o ip que eu tenho que retorna um vetor

> [124.15,1409.51,174988.56,95284.50,0.54,0.00,....]

Apenas isso, sem formatação, sem header, sem nada. Se for olha no código fonte da página só aparece o vetor.

Esse é um endereço interno da rede.

Seu colocar do google mostra

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Mas o meu mostra a mensagem:

> Parse error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira coisa a fazer para recriar uma requisição `HTTP` dentro do `Node.js` é identificar as informações que são enviadas em tal requisição.

Vou sugerir um passo a passo usando a `URL` `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/` como exemplo. Para isso você precisará do `Chrome`, do [**Postman**](https://www.getpostman.com/) e do módulo [**got**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) do `NPM`:

1. Abra uma aba vazia do `Chrome`, clique com o botão direito e selecione a opção `Inspecionar`. Uma nova janela com as `DevTools` será aberta (referenciando a nova aba que foi aberta anteriormente);

[image: Imagem 1]

[image: Imagem 2]

2. Acesse o endereço de destino;

[image: Imagem 3]

3. Identifique a requisição na guia `Network` das `DevTools`;

[image: Imagem 4]

4. Clique com o botão direito na requisição e selecione a opção `Copy > Copy as cURL (cmd);

[image: Imagem 5]

No caso da minha requisição o resultado foi:

```
curl "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" --compressed
```

5. No [**Postman**](https://www.getpostman.com/) clique na opção `Import` localizada no canto superior esquerdo e vá para a aba `Paste Raw Text`. Cole o comendo do `cURL` que foi obtido nas `DevTools` do `Chrome`;

[image: Imagem 6]

6. Ao importar, a requisição com todos os cabeçalhos (`Headers`) e informações necessárias será montada;

[image: Imagem 7]

7. Clique em `SEND` e verifique o resultado. Caso o status seja `200` a requisição foi executada com sucesso. Você pode verificar também o conteúdo da resposta na guia `Body`;

[image: Imagem 8]

Você pode usar o [**Postman**](https://www.getpostman.com/) para gerar o código do Node para você ou continuar com as opções a partir do passo 8. Para gerar o código você pode clicar na opção `code` do lado direito da janela e selecionar a linguagem que deseja;

[image: Imagem 9]

8. Depois de confirmar todos os dados da requisição, o código para execução instale o módulo [**got**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got):

   npm install got
9. O código para execução no `Node.js` com os parâmetros devidamente preenchidos será o seguinte:

---

```
(async () => {
  const { URLSearchParams } = require('url');
  const got = require('got');

  try {
    const params = new URLSearchParams({});
    const { body } = await got(`https://pt.stackoverflow.com?${params}`, {
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
      }
    });

    console.log(body)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
})();
```

---

Com as informações do `cURL` fornecidas pela requisição da sua pergunta:

```
curl "http://147.1.31.61/sistema.cgi?lermc=0,33:80" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;‌​q=0.8" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" --compressed
```

Teremos o seguinte código de execução:

```
(async () => {
  const { URLSearchParams } = require('url');
  const got = require('got');

  try {
    const params = new URLSearchParams({ 'lermc': '0,33:80' });
    const { body } = await got(`http://147.1.31.61/sistema.cgi?${params}`, {
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;‌​q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
      }
    });

    console.log(body)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
})();
```

Claro que devemos atentar também com algumas coisas, como por exemplo o `status` de devolução do serviço e o tipo da resposta, porém em essência com as informações acima é possível realizar a requisição.

Comment: O conteúdo da resposta é aquele vetor na pergunta que retorna. Que na verdade é uma string no formato de vetor: `"[123,654,855,1565,88656]"`

Comment: Deu essa mensagem `failed, reason: Parse Error`

Comment: @adventistaam fiz uma alteração, veja se resolve

Comment: Deu esse problema aqui "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://192.168.1.6/ failed, reason: Parse Error". Só o ip também retorna valor. Mas não no node

Comment: @adventistaam da um `console.log` no `params` antes do `fetch` para vermos o que ele está enviando.

Comment: @adventistaam fiz mais uma alteração no código, verifique se o problema é resolvido com ela.

Comment: Não deu erro, porém não mostrou nada rsrs.. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @adventistaam com qual alteração?

Comment: Com o `process.binding('http_parser')...`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82136/discussion-between-sorack-and-adventistaam).